# Hive - UNIX_TIMESTAMP Quandary

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

Here is my 1 line of data (for brevity):

```
73831   12/26/2014 1:00:00 AM   0.3220
```

The 2nd column is the `time` column which is in string format. I'm using this hive query:

```
select col2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col2,'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss aaa') from Table
```

Here is what I get: `1388296800`

However, when I check with, http://www.epochconverter.com/ and also `from_unixtime(1388296800)`, I get a different date.

Is there something wrong with my format / pattern string I enter into `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in Hive?

Comment: from_unixtime internally uses - Java - SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I checked using the code from Python and Java separately

Comment: Java Code import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
public class SimpleDateFormatExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
        Date curDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        String DateToStr = "12/26/2014 1:00:00 PM";
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss aaa");
        System.out.println(format.parse(DateToStr));
    }
}

Comment: prints - Sun Dec 29 13:00:00 EST 2013

Comment: Python code - // datetime.datetime.strptime("12/26/2014 1:00:00 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
//datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 26, 13, 0)

Comment: Python seems to have worked correctly :-)

Comment: Can you put these comments into the question? You can edit it after it's been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format symbols need to conform to those in the Java [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

For your date it looks like you want `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa`.