# Hive Unix Timestamp

Tags: apache, hive, hiveql

I'm not getting expected result from UNIX_TIMESTAMP of hive

For example :

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015/02/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')) from table limit 1;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
2014-12-28 00:00:00
Time taken: 0.287 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I expected it to return 2015-02-01 , but it resulted something else. I understand its probably because of epoch time ?

Comment: This is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884963/hive-unix-timestamp-quandary?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all caps in your date format.  Try this using lowercase:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/02/01','yyyy/MM/dd') from table;
```

Results in:
2015-02-01 00:00:00

Also you can strip off the time using:

```
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/02/01','yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

Results in:
2015-02-01

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr() function as well. works great everywhere, unless you need to compare it with other time variable/constant.

Answer (score -1):

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015/02/01'))
```

Use this Query to get the ans as `2015-02-01 00:00:00`

Thanks.

Comment: You can try with this `select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015/02/01 00:00:00'))